# Код из стороннего потока изменяет UI

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, ui

Во многих источниках говорится, что код из стороннего потока не может изменять экран приложения(UI) и для этого нужно использовать `Handler`, `runOnUiThread()` и т.д.
Так почему мой поток созданный в `onCreate()` изменяет `View` на экране и приложение не выдает ошибку?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_info);
        activity=this;
        intent = getIntent();
        final String[] selectionArgs = {""+intent.getLongExtra("id",-100)};
        oiNames = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oiNames);
        oiPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oiPhone);
        oiDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oiDate);
        oiCAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oiCAddress);
        oiTotalPayment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oiTotalPayment);

        llOIForItems =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llOIForItems);
        oillBackground = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.oillBackground);
       llFor1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llFor1);
        pBarOrder = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pBarOrder);
        final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyDataBase mDB = new MyDataBase(activity);
                SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = mDB.getWritableDatabase();

                Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(NAME_OF_CONNECTOR_TABLE,null,IDSH_CONNECTOR_TABLE+"= ?",
                        selectionArgs,null,null,null);
                Cursor cursorForProduct;
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    int idPColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(IDP_CONNECTOR_TABLE);
                    int amountColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(AMOUNT_CONNECTOR_TABLE);
                    int nameColIndex; //= cursor.getColumnIndex(NAME_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
                    int priceColIndex; //= cursor.getColumnIndex(PRICE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);*/
                    do{
                        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_order,null,false);
                        TextView itemName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
                        TextView itemAmount=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemAmount);
                        TextView itemPrice= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);
                        double val=0;


                        String[] idP = {""+cursor.getLong(idPColIndex)};
                        cursorForProduct = sqlDB.query(NAME_OF_PRODUCTS_TABLE,null,ID_PRODUCTS_TABLE+"= ?",
                                idP,null,null,null);
                        if(cursorForProduct.moveToFirst()){
                            nameColIndex = cursorForProduct.getColumnIndex(NAME_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
                            priceColIndex = cursorForProduct.getColumnIndex(PRICE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);

                            val= Double.parseDouble(cursorForProduct.getString(priceColIndex));
                            itemName.setText(cursorForProduct.getString(nameColIndex));
                            itemPrice.setText(String.format("%.2f",Double.parseDouble(cursorForProduct.getString(priceColIndex)) ));
                        }                            
                       itemAmount.setText(cursor.getString(amountColIndex));
                        totalPayment+=val*cursor.getLong(amountColIndex);
                        cursorForProduct.close();
                        llOIForItems.addView(itemView);
                    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                oiTotalPayment.setText(String.format("%.2f",totalPayment));
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: Может потому, что у Вас простое приложение и Вам пока везет? Как только в приложении будет достаточно много взаимодействия с интерфейсом, у вас начнутся проблемы с отображением.

Comment: А может оно у вас таки на главном потоке и исполняется? Проверьте как-то так, например: `Thread.currentThread().equals( Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() )`

Comment: Уже удалил эту часть. Думаю у меня произошло тоже что и по ссылке
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727254/why-non-ui-thread-can-modify-ui